# font file not found in virtual file system

Tags: datatables

I'm using Datatable js to manage my tables but facing a issue with encode `Arabic Words` when try export a pdf file,
so I'm trying to change the default font in `pdfMake`

so I did that

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>

 <script>
            pdfMake.fonts = {
                Arial: {
                    normal: 'Arial.ttf',
                    bold: 'Arial.ttf',
                    italics: 'Arial.ttf',
                    bolditalics: 'Arial.ttf'
                }
            };

 var buttons = new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(datatable, {
                    buttons: [{
                            extend: 'copyHtml5',
                            title: documentTitle
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'excelHtml5',
                            title: documentTitle
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'csvHtml5',
                            title: documentTitle
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                            title: documentTitle,
                            customize: function(doc) {
                                doc.defaultStyle.font = 'Arial';
                            },
                        }

                    ]
                }).container().appendTo($('#report_views_export'));
 </script>
```

but I'm getting that message in console `Uncaught (in promise) File 'Arial.ttf' not found in virtual file system`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the fonts in file `vfs_fonts.js`. To do that you must encode every font file to base 64 format and putting the base 64 string in the  file `vfs_fonts.js`.

File `vfs_fonts.js` will be like

```
this.pdfMake = this.pdfMake || {}; this.pdfMake.vfs = {
"arial.ttf": "AAEAAAAXAQAABABwRFNJRyQ9+ecAB..........",
"arialbd.ttf":"AAEAAAAXAQAABABwRFNJR8zIlFoA..........",
"ariali.ttf":"AAEAAAAXAQAABABwRFNJRy1JDhMAC..........",
"arialbi.ttf":"AAEAAAAYAQAABACARFNJRxk7cD4A.........."
};
```